# How can I ignore associates on fetching data using entityGraph?

Tags: jpa, entitygraph

I fetch using EntityGraph with needed attributes. I have to create new endpoint to fetch data with all associates without making DTO.

Is it possible and if yes how can I do this?

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM Entity e")
@EntityGraph(value = "Entity.excludeAssociations", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
Page\<Entity\> findAll(Pageable pageable);

    @EntityGraph(
            type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH,
            attributePaths = {
                    "entityAddress",
                    "contactMethods",
                    "tags",
                    "entityUser"
            }
    )
    Page<Entity> findAll(Specification<Entity> entitySpecification, Pageable pageable);
```